# Scheduling Salesforce functions

Tags: apex, webservices, scheduled-apex

I have a scenario where I have to schedule 3 functions residing in a class in succession with time gap of 1 minute between them.

The Schedulable class looks like

```
global class pullStepAndStatusTaleo Implements Schedulable
{

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
      method1();
      method2();
      method3();
    }

   //function 1
   @future (callout = true)
   webservice static void methdo1()
   {
        //function logic
   }

   //function 2
   @future (callout = true)
   webservice static void methdo2()
   {
        //function logic
   }

   //function 3
   @future (callout = true)
   webservice static void methdo3()
   {
        //function logic
   }
}
```

If method1() is called at t, method2() should be called at t+1 and method3() at t+2.
This set will be scheduled to run every 15mins.

Any help will be appreciated.

~Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off rescheduling new jobs 1 minute after each other (i.e. after each method has started/completed, schedule the next a minute later), and consider passing in the method to call as a constructor argument:

```
    // try again in a minute
Datetime sysTime = System.now().addSeconds( 60 );
String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();          
System.schedule( 'pullStepAndStatusTaleo ' + sysTime, chronExpression, new pullStepAndStatusTaleo(1) );
```

You would probably want to add the following after you've called your method in the `execute` method to avoid redundant scheduled jobs being left:

```
System.abortJob( sc.getJobTriggerId() );
```

Comment: This is the way I'd go.  You can't reliably schedule these to run in the time frame you are talking about (1 minute intervals).  Execution start times are not guaranteed when scheduling apex.